# insert and delete integers on the fly

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ and I was wondering how you would go about inserting and delete items on the fly from an array. For example:

```
>> insert(1)
[1]
>> insert(2)
[1,2]
>> delete()
[1]
```

I'm not interested in any libraries at the moment I just want to be able to grasp the fundamentals of C++. I should also mention that the array will have no values to begin with.

Comment: IMO it's noteworthy that the Standard Library (often called STL) is technically part of the C++ language. Also, Bjarne Stroustrup considers `std::vector` to be useful and important right from the start (see [Programming - Principles and Practice in C++](http://www.stroustrup.com/programming.html)).

Comment: @DyP this is for a class and we haven't covered anything with std so I am just going by what the teacher is showing us

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are not interested in STL containers(although I would advice you to look into it for eg `vector`), declare an array of whatever maximum size you want

```
int arr[10];
```

Now access the elements in an array through indexing and assign the value

```
arr[0] = 5;   //indexes start from 0 and in this case till 9
```

Or keep a variable for index as

```
int index = 0;
```

While inserting, use:

```
arr[index] = value;
index++;
```

While making an element in array available, just decrement the index to point that the later indexes are free to be filled.

EDIT:

See the code below:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int arr[10];
    int choice;
    int num;
    int index = 0;
    do
    {
        cout<<"enter you choice:\n";
        cout<<"1. add number\n";
        cout<<"2. delete number\n";
        cout<<"3. display memory\n";
        cout<<"anything else to exit\n";
        cin>>choice;
        switch(choice)
        {
        case 1:
            if(index==10)
            {
                cout<<"no more space available\n";
            }
            else
            {
                cout<<"enter number: ";
                cin>>num;
                arr[index++] = num;
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            if(index==0)
            {
                cout<<"memory empty\n";
            }
            else
            {
                cout<<"item deleted!\n ";
                index--;
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            for(int i = 0;i<index;i++)
            {
                cout<<arr[i]<<'\t';
            }
            cout<<endl;
            break;
        default:
            cout<<"exiting.......";
        }
    }while(choice>0 && choice<4);
}
```

Comment: can you show me a simple function that inserts and also remembers the index so if the user inserts another number again it doesnt override arr[0]

Comment: @Mr.1.0 rather than functions, you should consider writing a class that holds both the array and the current index.

Comment: @juanchopanza this is for a class assignment we haven't learned classes so we have to use functions

Comment: @Mr.1.0 OK, then you should state your requirements more clearly. For example, must `insert` have only one parameter? Must `delete` (bad name for a function in C++ BTW) have none?

Comment: @Mr.1.0 I would advice you to read a good book on c++, just the first few chapters and everything would be clear to you. One book would be `C++ for dummies`.

Comment: @Saksham its class work and i need to submit online in 30 minutes so i don't have time to ready it all.

Comment: @Mr.1.0 see my edit for code. This was my first and probably the last time on helping for someone's homework.

Comment: @Saksham I really appreciate that, but I want to learn it too. Do you mind going no http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/38950/menikmati?tab=general so I can ask you questions?

Comment: @Mr.1.0 I'm about to leave for work and then I am flying out. sorry but we could chat some other time.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

You can use `push_back` to insert in the back of the vector and `pop_back` to remove the last element.

An example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> numbers;
    numbers.push_back(1)
    numbers.push_back(2);
    numbers.pop_back();

    for (int i : numbers) { // c++11 range-based for loop
        std::cout << i << '\n';
    }
}
```

Prints 1 like in your example.

Answer (score 0):

take a look in `std::vector`

```
std::vector<int> arr;
arr.push_back(1);
arr.push_back(2);
arr.pop_back();
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing like that in the fundamentals of C++ you have to use a library (or write your own library of course). The standard library that you get with every C++ implementation has a class called `std::vector` that does what you want.

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a;
    a.push_back(1);
    a.push_back(2);
    a.pop_back();
}
```